# Mudar no IONIC 3 altura do ion-header/ion-navbar no Android

Tags: ionic, ionic3, app, header, nav-bar

Gostaria de saber como faço no ionic 3 para deixar a o cabeçalho do android igual ao IOS, ou seja, ocupando todo o espaço superior sem aparecer, aquela parte da divisão onde aparece as informações do celular( hora, bateria e etc).

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar>
<ion-title>Home</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Segue imagem de anexo....
Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]